# Problem for dynamically updating my html page every 5 seconds such that it shows the new data (Using flask)

Tags: python, html, flask

I am creating a simulated covid-care center in which i am using python's flask, html etc.
In this i will have a table showing some values at the home screen and then a chatbot and faq page. I have made the chat bot and faqs but i am having troubles updating my html data dynamically. (The data is created at the backend using random and thread modules).
Here is my main.py:

```
import flask
import time
import mysql.connector
app = flask.Flask(__name__)
app.static_folder = 'static'

#I am storing the values in a database
f = mysql.connector.connect(host = "localhost", user = "root", passwd = "")
mycur = f.cursor()
mycur.execute("use one_stop_healthcare;")
mycur.execute("select * from ccinfo;")
lines = mycur.fetchall()

@app.route("/")
def print_val():
    global lines
    return flask.render_template("index.html", lines = lines)

app.run()
```

Here is my index.html which is stored in a templates directory:

```
<html>
    <style>
        table, th, td {
          border: 1px solid black;
          border-collapse: collapse;
        }
        th, td {
            padding: 15px;
            text-align: center;
          }
        .button {
            border: none;
            color: white;
            padding: 15px 32px;
            text-align: center;
            text-decoration: none;
            display: inline-block;
            font-size: 16px;
            margin: 4px 2px;
            cursor: pointer;
            }
            
            .button1 {background-color: #4CAF50;} /* Green */
            .button2 {background-color: #008CBA;} /* Blue */
            
        </style>
    <head> 
        <title> One Stop Healthcare </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2> The data for all the COVID care centers </h1>
        <table style="width:100%">
            <tr>
                <th> ID </th>
                <th> NAME </th>
                <th> LOCATION </th>
                <th> BEDS </th>
                <th> DISCARGED </th>
                <th> ACTIVE </th>
                <th> DEAD </th>
                <th> DOCTORS </th>
                <th> MONEY </th>
                <th> PPE_KITS </th>
                <th> BLANKETS </th>
                <th> MASKS </th>
                <th> SANITIZER </th>
            </tr>
            {% for line in lines %}
                <tr>
                    {% for i in line %}

                        <td>{{ i }}</td> 

                    {% endfor %}
                </tr>

            {% endfor %}
        </table>
        <button type="button"><a href="http://127.0.0.1:5000/chatbot"> Chatbot </a></button>
        <button type="button"><a href="http://127.0.0.1:5000/faq"> FAQs </a></button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is my database + inserting the values into the database (You just need to run this once to insert the values and create the database). It doesn't have a issue

```
import mysql.connector

f = mysql.connector.connect(host = "localhost", user = "root", passwd = "")
mycur = f.cursor()
mycur.execute("create database One_Stop_Healthcare;")
f.commit()
mycur.execute("use One_Stop_Healthcare;")
print("database created")

que = "create table ccinfo(ID INTEGER NOT NULL primary key, NAME varchar(20), LOCATION varchar(20), BEDS integer, DISCHARGED integer, ACTIVE integer, DEAD integer, DOCTORS integer, MONEY integer, PPE_KITS integer, BLANKETS integer, MASKS integer, SANITIZER integer);"
mycur.execute(que)
print("table created")

mycur.execute("insert into ccinfo(ID, NAME, LOCATION, BEDS, DISCHARGED, ACTIVE, DEAD, DOCTORS, MONEY , PPE_KITS, BLANKETS, MASKS, SANITIZER)values(1, 'Ward-1', 'KRM', 500, 100, 300, 50, 25, 100000, 20, 100, 100, 70);") 
mycur.execute("insert into ccinfo(ID, NAME, LOCATION, BEDS, DISCHARGED, ACTIVE, DEAD, DOCTORS, MONEY , PPE_KITS, BLANKETS, MASKS, SANITIZER)values(2, 'Ward-2', 'KRM', 1000, 290, 700, 150, 78, 250000, 40, 600, 300, 130);") 
mycur.execute("insert into ccinfo(ID, NAME, LOCATION, BEDS, DISCHARGED, ACTIVE, DEAD, DOCTORS, MONEY , PPE_KITS, BLANKETS, MASKS, SANITIZER)values(3, 'Ward-3', 'KRM', 50, 10, 30, 5, 5, 80000, 7, 50, 30, 40);") 
mycur.execute("insert into ccinfo(ID, NAME, LOCATION, BEDS, DISCHARGED, ACTIVE, DEAD, DOCTORS, MONEY , PPE_KITS, BLANKETS, MASKS, SANITIZER)values(4, 'Ward-4', 'HSR', 1500, 400, 1300, 250, 100, 400000, 70, 500, 300, 150);") 
mycur.execute("insert into ccinfo(ID, NAME, LOCATION, BEDS, DISCHARGED, ACTIVE, DEAD, DOCTORS, MONEY , PPE_KITS, BLANKETS, MASKS, SANITIZER)values(5, 'Ward-5', 'Bellandur', 500, 50, 100, 25, 40, 90000, 30, 100, 90, 90);") 

f.commit()
```

And finally here is where i am simulating the data

````
import threading 
import time
import random
import mysql.connector

TC=5  #Total thread count

count = 0
thr = [0 for i in range(TC)]
db_data = [[] for i in range(TC+1)]

def print_time(): 
    global count
    global db_data
    
    count = count + 1
    mylocal = count   
    '''
    1: id
    2: location
    3: beds
    4: discharged
    5: active
    6: dead
    7: doctors
    8: money
    9: ppe kits
    10: blankets
    11: masks
    12: sanitizer
    '''
    i = 0
    while i < 5:
        i = i+1
        x = random.randint(1,350)
        #print(x)
        if x == 1:
            db_data[mylocal][3] = db_data[mylocal][3] + 50
            st = "UPDATE ccinfo SET BEDS = {} where ID = {}".format(db_data[mylocal][3], mylocal)
        elif x == 2 and db_data[mylocal][3] > 50:
            db_data[mylocal][3] = db_data[mylocal][3] - 50
            st = "UPDATE ccinfo SET BEDS = {} where ID = {}".format(db_data[mylocal][3], mylocal)
        elif x == 3:
            db_data[mylocal][7] = db_data[mylocal][7] + 1
            st = "UPDATE ccinfo SET DOCTORS = {} where ID = {}".format(db_data[mylocal][7], mylocal)
        elif x == 4 and db_data[mylocal][7] > 7:
            db_data[mylocal][7] = db_data[mylocal][7] - 1
            st = "UPDATE ccinfo SET DOCTORS = {} where ID = {}".format(db_data[mylocal][7], mylocal)
        elif x > 4 and x < 101:
            db_data[mylocal][4] = db_data[mylocal][4] + 1
            st = "UPDATE ccinfo SET DISCHARGED = {} where ID = {}".format(db_data[mylocal][4], mylocal)
        elif x > 100 and x < 201:
            db_data[mylocal][5] = db_data[mylocal][5] + 1
            st = "UPDATE ccinfo SET ACTIVE = {} where ID = {}".format(db_data[mylocal][5], mylocal)
        elif x > 200 and x < 211:
            db_data[mylocal][6] = db_data[mylocal][6] + 1
            st = "UPDATE ccinfo SET DEAD = {} where ID = {}".format(db_data[mylocal][6], mylocal)
        elif x > 210 and x < 221:
            db_data[mylocal][8] = db_data[mylocal][8] + 10000
            st = "UPDATE ccinfo SET MONEY = {} where ID = {}".format(db_data[mylocal][8], mylocal)
        elif x > 220 and x < 231 and db_data[mylocal][8] > 20000:
            db_data[mylocal][8] = db_data[mylocal][8] - 10000
            st = "UPDATE ccinfo SET MONEY = {} where ID = {}".format(db_data[mylocal][8], mylocal)
        elif x > 230 and x < 241:
            db_data[mylocal][9] = db_data[mylocal][9] + 5
            st = "UPDATE ccinfo SET PPE_KITS = {} where ID = {}".format(db_data[mylocal][9], mylocal)
        elif x > 240 and x < 251 and db_data[mylocal][9] > 0:
            db_data[mylocal][9] = db_data[mylocal][9] - 5
            st = "UPDATE ccinfo SET PPE_KITS = {} where ID = {}".format(db_data[mylocal][9], mylocal)
        elif x > 250 and x < 261:
            db_data[mylocal][10] = db_data[mylocal][10] + 5
            st = "UPDATE ccinfo SET BLANKETS = {} where ID = {}".format(db_data[mylocal][10], mylocal)
        elif x > 260 and x < 271 and db_data[mylocal][10] > 0:
            db_data[mylocal][10] = db_data[mylocal][10] - 5
            st = "UPDATE ccinfo SET BLANKETS = {} where ID = {}".format(db_data[mylocal][10], mylocal)
        elif x > 270 and x < 281:
            db_data[mylocal][11] = db_data[mylocal][11] + 5
            st = "UPDATE ccinfo SET MASKS = {} where ID = {}".format(db_data[mylocal][11], mylocal)
        elif x > 280 and x < 291 and db_data[mylocal][11] > 0:
            db_data[mylocal][11] = db_data[mylocal][11] - 5
            st = "UPDATE ccinfo SET MASKS = {} where ID = {}".format(db_data[mylocal][11], mylocal)
        elif x > 290 and x < 301:
            db_data[mylocal][12] = db_data[mylocal][12] + 5
            st = "UPDATE ccinfo SET SANITIZER = {} where ID = {}".format(db_data[mylocal][12], mylocal)
        elif x > 300 and x < 311 and db_data[mylocal][12] > 0:
            db_data[mylocal][12] = db_data[mylocal][12] - 5
            st = "UPDATE ccinfo SET SANITIZER = {} where ID = {}".format(db_data[mylocal][12], mylocal)
        print(st)
        mycur.execute(st)
        f.commit()
        time.sleep(10)
                
if __name__ == "__main__": 
    f = mysql.connector.connect(host = "localhost", user = "root", passwd = "")
    mycur = f.cursor()
    mycur.execute("use one_stop_healthcare;")
    mycur.execute("select * from ccinfo;")
    dat = mycur.fetchall()
    

    for val in dat:
        i = val[0]
        db_data[i] = list(val)  
    print(db_data)
    for i in range(TC):
        thr[i] = threading.Thread(target=print_time)
        thr[i].start()
        time.sleep(1)
    for i in range(TC):
        thr[i].join()
```
````

Answer (score 0):

Simply add this `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5">` to your `HTML` in the `head`

Comment: Hey thanks for the advice but i tried that and it refreshed the page every 5 seconds but the data remained the same. To verify i checked the database and the values had changed there.

Comment: @PranshuGoel Try adding a call to the function which is pulling the data in the HTML. Something like this `<body>
 <p>{{ myfunction() }}</p>
</body>`

Comment: Where exactly is the function which is pulling the data from the external database?

Comment: Hey in my main.py, when i render_template("index.html", lines=lines) it is when i sent the lines (which is in the format of a list in list) and then in html i use jinja2 to add the data in a table. Otherwise in my main.py i get the data from mycur.execute("select * from ccinfo;")

Comment: @PranshuGoel I don't understand where exactly you are pulling the data "from". Which database gets updated but yours don't?  Anyways, if it is `print_time` for e.g which pulls the data..just add a call for it in the jinja template `{{ print_time }}` to see weather it is a problem with the function or was it because you only call the function once. That ways  the function will pull data every time at page refresh